# Architecture for distributed impression data collection

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, avro, amazon-kinesis

I have a web application written in node.js spread out among several load-balanced web servers for an ad-tech project I'm working on. I am trying to figure out how to best collect and distribute log data for ad impressions served so I can analyze the data later.

We've decided to store the data in Apache Avro format and we're going to use Apache Spark to process the data. We chose Avro because of the way we're going to be accessing the data, and it seems like the best fit.

Currently I have a Kinesis Firehose stream setup and I use the AWS-SDK for Node.js to send Avro data about each impression to then ultimately be stored in S3. The problem Kinesis concatenates all of the files that I send to it for each batch it writes to S3 -- so if I have it configured to write every 300 seconds, then it'll queue up all the Avro files, concatenate them, and then write them to S3. The resulting files are no longer valid Avro files since they're merged together.

Maybe it would be better if I just send the raw JSON data to a Kinesis stream and then have another application convert the JSON data into Avro? Kind of annoying to have to write another service just for intermediate data processing though, and I would have to coordinate changes to the source data format with my transformation service.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Kinesis streams would work, but as you say perhaps a lot of work for what you need and then you need a service running 24x7x365 to consume the stream.

I do a very similar processing as you (though I am not using AVRO), but I have an S3 event notification on my firehose bucket, so every time firehose writes out a new file, a Lambda function gets called that does the minor amount of cleanup that I need to do to get the data into the final format for eventual loading by another system, and then writes it back out to another seperate location.

Depending on how different the concatenated firehose events are for you, vs what AVRO needs, this may be only a minor transformation and since you are already coding in nodejs writing a Lamba nodejs function to transform the data should be pretty easy for you.